# Javascript console error when adding classList.add to array

Tags: javascript, error-code

Hi trying to understand and fix the console error I'm getting when running the following code [full code here](http://codepen.io/makingsnippets/pen/GrLbom/)

```
for(var i = 0 ; i <= paragraphs.length ; i++){
  if( i === 0 ){
    continue
  }
  paragraphs[i].classList.add('hide')
}
```

The error reads

```
Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined
```

I found [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/learnjavascript/comments/4a96f9/getting_a_js_error_with_classlist_uncaught/) explanation on reddit but I was not sure how it had been fixed?

Many thanks in advance

Comment: you could save the if clause by starting from `1`.

Comment: _In JavaScript arrays (and array-like objects) are zero-indexed: the first element of an array is at index 0, and the last element is at the index equal to the value of the array's length property minus 1._ ([ref.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array#Accessing_array_elements))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are out of your array on your loop.

Do this :

```
for(var i = 0 ; i < paragraphs.length ; i++)
```

Instead of

```
for(var i = 0 ; i <= paragraphs.length ; i++)
```

You can optimized your loop to begin on the second item directly ("**i = 1** instead of "**i =0**")

Answer (score 2):

Your loop exceeds the number of your paragraphs to solve it you must:

1 - paragraphs.length-1

or

2 - i < paragraphs.length

```
var paragraphs = document.getElementsByTagName('p'),
    firstParagraph = paragraphs[0],
    link = document.createElement('a');
    link.innerHTML = 'Show more';
    link.setAttribute('class' , 'link');
    link.setAttribute('href' , '#');
    firstParagraph.appendChild(link);
        for(var i = 0 ; i <= paragraphs.length-1 ; i++){
          if( i === 0 ){
            continue
          }
          console.log("hellp",paragraphs[i]);
          paragraphs[i].classList.add('hide')
        }
```